# How to boost::bind to a boost::math::pdf?

Tags: c++, boost

To get a value of the Probability Density Function of the normal distribution, you're supposed to do

```
boost::math::normal nd;
std::cout << boost::math::pdf( nd, 0.0 );
```

for example. I wanted do get the pdf function by itself using `boost::bind` and tried

```
boost::function< double ( double ) > fpdf = boost::bind(
    boost::math::pdf, nd, _1 );
```

first. That did not work, apparently because `boost::math::pdf` is templated.

Then I tried

```
boost::function< double ( double ) > fpdf = boost::bind(
    boost::math::pdf< boost::math::normal, double >, nd, _1 );
```

and got the typical 1000 error messages resulting from heavily templated code, one of the being [compiler error C2784](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/wf867f8f%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `boost::bind` is not able to deduce return value type.

Try this:

```
boost::function< double ( double ) > fpdf = boost::bind<double>(
  boost::math::pdf< boost::math::normal, double >, nd, _1 );
```

Comment: Very nice. Typical case of template compiler error deciphering failure on my side.